# Chrome app, change html between pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to create a chrome app that has something going on in the main screen, and in the side it has 2 buttons which work like tabs to switch the content in the sidebar. In other languages (QT for example) I would create 3 forms:

- The main window
- Content for tab 1
- Content for tab 2

Then in the main window I add a tag which gets replaced by the content of either tab 1 or tab 2. Can I do something similar in a chrome app? Or, what would a better way to do this?

Comment: A Chrome app is built with your typical HTML + JS. You can use any of the UI techniques and frameworks available to build your application.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Not _quite_ true, as [some Web API features are disabled](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated); most importantly navigation - you have to build a single-page web app.

Comment: Thanks, I think I just needed a different mindset for this. I am known with navigation in webbrowsers, and with ui in other languages. I will have to learn the single-page web app approach.